# jquery focusout event missing relatedTarget information

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, focusout

i have a text input that is bound to `focusin`/`focusout` events.

```
$(element)
    .focusin(function(e) {})
    .focusout(function(e) {
        var to = e.relatedTarget || e.toElement;
        // undefined in chrome, fine in IE
    });
```

on `focusout`, i'm interested in the `relatedTarget` information, i.e., the DOM element receiving focus as the text input loses focus, however this property is `undefined` for the event.

on the other hand, `toElement`, which i believe is the internet explorer equivalient of `relatedTarget`, is available.  in other words, my `focusout` handler works fine in IE, but not in other browsers.

is there a workaround for the above limitation?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From [the MDC docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.relatedTarget):

> Only MouseEvents have this property

`focusout` is not a mouse event, so `relatedTarget` is not set. IE is not following standards here (what's new?).

Comment: @ob If you read that page, it will explain further that only *some* mouse events have `relatedTarget` set. `mousedown` is not one of them. It doesn't make semantic sense.

Comment: right, but on mousedown i could check e.target.  won't necessarily need relatedTarget in that case.

Comment: Are you sure this is still the case? Looking at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/focusout (last updated Jun 19, 2014 1:31:51 AM), I see that the property is available.

Comment: relatedTarget is part of the DOM level-3 Event specification for focus, blur, focusin and focusout.