# jQuery - click on button shown on focusin

Tags: jquery

I want to show a button on focusin, do some action when clicked or hide that button on focusout:

```
$(".editableDiv").live('focusin', function(){
    // show button under the .editableDiv div

    $("#button").live('click', function(){
        // do action
    });
    $(".editableDiv").live('focusout', function(){
        // hide button
    });
});
```

It shows the button on focus but when the button is clicked, the action is ignored and the button is immediately hidden like if focusout had priority over click. When I try to remove that focusout part, the action gets done but button stays visible... but I need to hide that button on focusout.

It seems so simple... but I cannot figure out why it's not working - any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the action that you're performing `onclick`? And you could move the binding of `click` to the button out of the `focusin` handler since it's being bound by id.

Comment: You really, really shouldn't use live. Use `delegate()` http://paulirish.com/2010/on-jquery-live/

Comment: Also, can you show us this on jsbin.com or something?

Comment: Is the button inside the div or outside it?

Comment: @no.good.at.coding - the action is lengthy function that grabs content of a div with contentEditable=true and does some operations with it. I didn't want to complicate this question with it - the action is done just fine when that focusout part is removed. And I had that button out of focusin handler originally but it made no difference at all. Actually I was trying to fix it by moving it inside of the focusin handler:(

Comment: @justkt - it's outside of it. It's like the focusout part is done before the click part could be done.

Comment: What's happening on click of the button? Why not hide it when you click it, instead of onfocusout?

Comment: @Oscar Godson - thank you, I will read that article.

Comment: Sure thing, in short, its a lot slower. Lots of issues with bubbling and on mobile devices there's a noticeable delay before the event happens.

Comment: @Jared Farrish - because the button is shown to show users they can click on it and change the content of the focused div... but they don't have to. They might just leave it and focus out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening is that the focusout is firing and hiding your button before it can receive the click event.

So why not just hide the button on click/focusout after a few milliseconds??

```
$(".editableDiv").live('focusin', function(){
    // show button under the .editableDiv div
    $("#button").show();
}).live('focusout', function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#button").hide();
    },50);
});
$("#button").live('click', function(){
    // hide button
    alert('test');
    $("#button").hide();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/E2Cyx/2/

Comment: After playing around with it extensively, this is the right answer.

Comment: @justkt - Thanks, I've had to do similar before. @honzzz - If you consider it the right answer, click the outlined checkmark below the vote tally to the left of the answer. :)

Comment: @honzzz - I just tried this on a laptop that's not particularly fast and 50 milliseconds was too fast; you might bump it up to 250 or 500 on the `setTimeout()`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to shuffle your handler assignments around a bit.  Right now the button click and focusout handlers are only bound on the first focusin.

On top of that there is the problem of [not being able to know](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4652430/jquery-focusout-event-missing-relatedtarget-information) (without using IE specific information), what event triggered the focusout (so you can't isolate the button as the source).  The best solution appears to be a timeout solution.  I'd suggest code such as that provided in [this answer to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5747283/jquery-click-on-button-shown-on-focusin/5747355#5747355).

Comment: Oops, I had the actions backwards. I think the problem still exists, mainly, that the button is getting hidden before it can receive the click: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/RqGKd/1/

Comment: This produces the same result as my code above. The focusout seems to hide the button before the click on it can be registered.

Answer (score 0):

It's just that when you click on a button, you're essentially focussing on IT, and therefore, it fires the focusout/blur event for whatever just had the focus.

Comment: It seems like it - but how can i avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to prevent event propagation on that button click handler, because if not, the buttons gains focus, and the focusout function is invoked.

```
$("#button").live('click', function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  //do your thing...
});
```

Comment: It seems that the click is not even invoked because the focusout function is invoked before that... so adding .stopPropagation() inside of that click function is not invoked either.

Comment: Yes, that's correct! the click event binding must come out of the focusin